# Why does Git GUI keep calling me Jon Skeet?

Tags: git, author, git-gui, attribution

As a joke, I named my laptop's user account Jon Skeet. I've configured my per-repository options to call me `wizzwizz4`, yet when I view my commits I see this:

```
Author: Jon Skeet <jon@myLaptop>  2018-12-21 22:07:11
Committer: wizzwizz4 <wizzwizz4@users.noreply.github.com>  2018-12-21 22:12:07
Parent: 39c31f5aebe43cdddbe00432207e4bb2cc6a777e (Initial commit)
Branches: master
Follows: 
Precedes:
```

Why does it keep doing this when my repository settings clearly state my intentions? I don't want Jon getting credit for *my* code! Committing from the command-line has the expected result.

Comment: Did you do a commit before you changed your repository settings? And did you by any chance then rebase or amend that commit? The timestamps suggest such a situation, which would explain why the author still contains the old name, while the committer already has the new configuration.

Comment: Please update the question with the relevant bits from the comments so the comments can be cleaned out. This would increase the value of the question for others.

Comment: Probably similar issue: https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1364 ? (`user.useConfigOnly`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple ways that can occur.  Before we get to them all, we will need to cover appropriate background information.  It's also worth emphasizing a key item: **No data in any existing commit can be altered, not even a single bit.**  As long as commit `39c31f5aebe43cdddbe00432207e4bb2cc6a777e` exists in your repository, it will continue to have the same information.  (Note that this is the *parent* of the commit you showed.  You did not show the actual hash ID of the commit itself, so I couldn't use that one.)

In the very specific case of Git-GUI ([`git-gui.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/git-gui.sh), which I never use), it looks from the [source](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-gui/lib/commit.tcl) as though there is a feature where using "amend" reads the `HEAD` commit's author information and replicates it.  It generally *should* do this when you select "amending" (which, as noted above and below, is a white lie) and *should not* do this when not-amending.  Unlike command-line `git commit`, there appears to be no Git-GUI knob to do an amend while not retaining the author.  If it's accidentally applying the author retaining to *all new* commits, that's just a bug.

For more, read on.

#### Background

Every commit has some *metadata* associated with it.  There are two relevant metadata lines in the raw commit object, called the *author* and the *committer*.  These two are typically, but not necessarily, the same, as one can see from various commits in the Git repository for Git itself.   For instance:

```
$ git cat-file -p 5d826e972970a784bd7a7bdf587512510097b8c7
tree c790c47fe551d5ed812cfefdac243eb972c1fde3
parent b5796d9a3263b26a8ef32eeca76b3c1d62fcedc5
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1544328981 +0900
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1544328981 +0900

Git 2.20

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(I've replaced `@` with  to possibly cut down on spam harvesting).  But:

```
$ git cat-file -p 6fcbad87d476d7281832af843dd448c94673fbfc
tree aa05bc7af6e92f3db5d5d738adf0d0b1b3dd23b6
parent b00bf1c9a8dd5009d5102aef7af9e2b886b1e5ad
author Johannes Sixt <j6t kdbg.org> 1543858489 +0100
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1543891852 +0900

rebase docs: fix incorrect format of [... snip]
```

Note that there are actually three parts to each of the two fields: full name, email address in <angle brackets>, and timestamp-with-zone-offset.

When you make a new commit using `git commit`, Git *usually sets both author and committer to the same three strings*.  But many Git commands copy some existing commit to a new-and-improved replacement.  The new commit has a new and different hash ID, by definition, but is meant to be used *instead of* the old one.  For these cases, Git normally preserves the original *author* information and sets you (and now) as the *committer*.

For reference, the author-preserving commit-copying commands are `git commit` with either of the `--amend` or the `-c` / `-C` options; `git cherry-pick`; and `git rebase`.  The `git am` command is meant to turn emailed patches into commits: it takes something other than a *commit* as its input, so we could say it's author-preserving, but then we have to define what we mean by *author*.  In this case, `git am` guesses at the authorship information by parsing a mailbox-formatted message.

#### Mechanisms for each field

There is a single underlying Git command, `git commit-tree`, that other commands either use, or have built into them.  This actually builds the commit object, which contains the above metadata.  It can take various directives to set each field individually.  If some field is *not* set, `git commit-tree` can take a default value from somewhere.

Since there are six parts—name, email-address, and time-stamp for each of author and committer—there are six places to get specific directives, and many places—not six this time!—to get defaults.  First, though, let's enumerate the primary six.

Rather than taking command-line options, `git commit-tree` takes these six items from *environment variables*, as described in [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-commit-tree.html):

> ```
> GIT_AUTHOR_NAME
> GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL
> GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
> GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
> GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
> GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
> ```

If you set *any or all* of these variables, that sets the value that will go into *all subsequent new commits* (until you unset the variables or your session with this environment expires, unsetting the variables).

If not, well, the documentation goes on to say:

> In case (some of) these environment variables are not set, the
>    information is taken from the configuration items user.name and
>    user.email, or, if not present, the environment variable EMAIL, or, if
>    that is not set, system user name and the hostname used for outgoing
>    mail (taken from `/etc/mailname` and falling back to the fully qualified
>    hostname when that file does not exist).

This is a bit of a white lie, as the actual code path taken depends on compile-time options, so that different Git installations can have different customized defaults.  But the general overall idea is correct: Git will use your `user.name` and `user.email` setting first, for both author and committer, if you have not overridden one or both with the various environment variables.

The default timestamp, of course, is simply your own computer's idea of the current time.  The relatively new `user.useConfigOnly` setting tells modern Git not to *guess* at `user.name` and/or `user.email`.  In older versions of Git, Git did no guessing: if these were not set, `git commit-tree` and `git commit` would just fail with an error message, saying that it did not know who you are.

The `git commit` front-end command also takes `--author` and `--date` as arguments.  These arguments can specify the user name, email address, and/or time-stamp to use in the new commit; `git commit` effectively implements these by setting, for the duration of the commit operation, the `GIT_AUTHOR_*` variables.

When using the `git commit` front end with the `--amend` flag—which, despite its name, does not actually *change* a commit; it just makes a new one to use *instead of* the current one, with all that this implies—the `--reset-author` flag tells the front end not to preserve the original commit's author information.

#### Conclusion

If *new* commits are getting the wrong author, while getting the right committer, one of two things must be the case:

- You're using `--author`.  Stop!
- You have `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` set in your environment.  Stop setting them!

If you have some existing commit, and you're trying to replace with a new and improved commit via `git commit --amend`, but it is retaining its author setting, simply add `--reset-author`.  Of course, this only works from the command line.  If you're using something else, find out if it has a similar option.

If some *existing* commit has the wrong author, you're stuck with that.  You can copy the existing, not-so-good, commit to a new and improved commit, and try to convince everyone else who has a copy of this same repository—a clone—to pick up and use the new-and-improved commit instead of the old one.  How hard *that* will be obviously depends on how stubborn the other users are, and also where the commit is.

Commits that are at the tip of their branch, and are not on any other branch, are quite easy to swap out, using `git commit --amend`.  Commits further back in history are more difficult: you can use interactive rebase, or `git replace`, or, in particularly ugly cases, `git filter-branch`, to swap them out (sometimes combining these techniques).  Any "change" to an older commit necessarily ripples down through all of its descendants by design,<sup>1</sup> so this kind of change can be quite disruptive.  However, if it's "changing"—replacing, really—history that no one else has ever seen, it's safe enough.

---

<sup>1</sup>The immediate children of a "bad" commit contain the bad commit's parent hash ID.  Hence, to get the children to refer to the replacement, we must *replace the children too*.  That means we must then replace *their* children, and so on down the line, all the way to the tip commits of each affected branch.

Comment: Your assumption was exactly right; I did keep seeing this via amending commits after changing the settings! (I was committing to several different projects.) I'm just going to set `user.useConfigOnly`...